# Xamarin NUnitLite testing methods: How to do shared tests that run in every platform?

Tags: c#, ios, unit-testing, xamarin, nunit

First thing I must say is that I'm not really sure about how to phrase this questions since I'm new to Xamarin.

I'm building an app in Xamaring with the aim of being Cross Platform.

These are the steps:

1. Create Solution
2. New Project, name: `Demo.UI.TestHarness.iOS`, type: iOS Unified Unit Test App
3. New Project, name: `Demo.UnitTests`, type: Cross-Platform Portable Library
4. Make `Demo.UI.TestHarness.iOS` the startup project
5. Add Nuget package `NUnitLite` to `Demo.UnitTests`
6. Add Reference to `Demo.UnitTests` in `Demo.UI.TestHarness.iOS`

This done, I created a class DummyTest in `Demo.UnitTests`:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Demo.UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class DummyTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void DUMMY ()
        {
            Assert.True (false);
        }
    }
}
```

And I added to the file `UnitTestAppDelegate` in `Demo.UI.TestHarness.iOS` a reference to this `DummyTest`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MonoTouch.NUnit.UI;
using Demo.UnitTests;

namespace Demo.UI.TestHarness.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register ("UnitTestAppDelegate")]
    public partial class UnitTestAppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;
        TouchRunner runner;

        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            runner = new TouchRunner (window);

            // register every tests included in the main application/assembly
            // runner.Add (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ());
            runner.Add(typeof(DummyTest).Assembly);

            window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController (runner.GetViewController ());

            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can build the project and run the debugger simulation, but no tests show up.

If instead I add the `DummyTest` directly inside my `Demo.UI.TestHarness.iOS` project and completely forget about the `Demo.UnitTests` project, it runs as intended (but this is not what I want because I want to make the tests all together to later use the same tests for Android and Mac and not having to redo them for every platform).

Comment: I usually split my tests into portable unit tests (which sounds like your `Demo.UnitTests`) which have no platform dependencies. Those unit tests I run with a NUnit library (just on my dev machine, not on devices). For anything that is dependent on the device, I write the unit tests directly in the iOS (or other platform) Unit Test App since I can't share a test that is dependent on a specific platform. This way my shared tests get to run very quickly and easily. This is just my take on 1 way to setup testing.

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone else is wondering why this does not work - here is what my research led me to:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16909/cant-test-pcl-test-assembly-from-xamarin-android-nunitlite-or-monotouch-nunit-ui

Specifically the post by "Seb Bartholomew". In his reply he posts a work around (which I have not tried yet). The basic issue is:

Xamarin.iOS uses MonoTouch.NUnitLite, Xamarin.Android uses Xamarin.Android.NUnitLite and the PCL used the base NUnit nuget package.

Although the assemblies have the same names and belong to the same namespaces they are intact different types so the Monotouch test runner does not detect the external [Test] attributes.

Comment: I switched to XUnit to do the tests. They are just not well integrated in Xamarin Studio, but work well in the different platforms.